# how to properly run Python script with crontab on every system startup

Tags: python, cron

I have a Python script that should open my Linux terminal, browser, file manager and text editor on system startup. I decided `crontab` is a suitable way to automatically run the script. Unfortunately, it doesn't went well, nothing happened when I reboot my laptop. So, I captured the output of the script to a file in order to get some clues. It seems my script is only partially executed. I use Debian 8 (Jessie), and here's my Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import webbrowser

def action():
    subprocess.call('gnome-terminal')
    subprocess.call('subl')
    subprocess.call(('xdg-open', '/home/fin/Documents/Learning'))
    webbrowser.open('https://reddit.com/r/python')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    action()
```

here's the entry in my `crontab` file:

```
@reboot python3 /home/fin/Labs/my-cheatcodes/src/dsktp_startup_script/dsktp_startup_script.py > capture_report.txt
```

Here's the content of capture_report.txt file (I trim several lines, since its too long, it only prints my folder structures. seems like it came from '`xdg-open`' line on Python script):

```
Directory list of /home/fin/Documents/Learning/

                    Type       Format     Sort
                   [Tree    ] [Standard] [By Name] [Update]
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
/  
... the rest of my dir stuctures goes here
```

I have no other clue what's possible going wrong here. I really appreciate your advice guys. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `cron` is not suitable for this. The `cron` daemon has no connection to your user's desktop session, which will not be running at system startup, anyway.

My recommendation would be to hook into your desktop environment's login scripts, which are responsible for starting various desktop services for you when you log in, anyway, and easily extended with your own scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do as tripleee suggested, but your job might be failing because it requires an [X session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), since you're trying to open a browser. You should put `export DISPLAY=:0;` after the schedule in your cronjob, as in

```
@reboot export DISPLAY=:0; python3 /home/fin/Labs/my-cheatcodes/src/dsktp_startup_script/dsktp_startup_script.py > capture_report.txt
```

If this doesn't work, you could try replacing `:0` with the output of `echo $DISPLAY` in a graphical terminal.